# SP 2013 webparts, hidden property check box greyed out

Tags: 2013, web-part, sharepoint-on-prem, hidden

SP 2013.
Hidden checkbox on webparts, regardless if the said webpart has got chrome set to none or default or other, is grayed out on wiki pages. On a site collection with publishing features and site with publishing features turned on.

Is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug, but opening the site on IE compatibility mode resolves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that out-of-the-box if you set the chrome to none and minimize the webpart (via its own menu) it looks like it is not there.

Workaround if you do not want to use coding.